# uninitialized constant Object::Dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object

I am trying to install fiveruns_tuneup but this error pops up... 
nothing found in google =(

Installation guide took from this page: https://github.com/fiveruns/fiveruns_tuneup

Thx.

more info:

```
    rake -v
    rake aborted!
    uninitialized constant Object::Dependencies
    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    *******@******:~/ag$ rake -v --trace
    rake aborted!
    uninitialized constant Object::Dependencies
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in     `const_missing'
    /home/skydos/ag/fiveruns_tuneup/ruby/1.9.1/gems/fiveruns_tuneup-  0.8.20/lib/fiveruns_tuneup.rb:1:in 
    `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 leve
ls) in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in requ
ire'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
/home/skydos/ag/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `re
quire'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `re
quire'
/home/skydos/ag/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rake
file'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_
rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exce
ption_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exce
ption_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

And:

```
****@***:~/ag$ rails -v
Rails 3.1.1.rc1
***@***:~/ag$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
***@***:~/ag$ gem list --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.1.1, 3.1.1.rc1, 3.1.0)
actionpack (3.1.1, 3.1.1.rc1, 3.1.0)
activemodel (3.1.1, 3.1.1.rc1, 3.1.0)
activerecord (3.1.1, 3.1.1.rc1, 3.1.0)
activeresource (3.1.1, 3.1.1.rc1, 3.1.0)
activesupport (3.1.1, 3.1.1.rc1, 3.1.0)
ansi (1.4.1, 1.3.0)
arel (2.2.1)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.21)
coffee-rails (3.1.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.1.3, 1.1.2)
daemon_controller (0.2.6)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.2.9, 1.2.6)
fastthread (1.0.7)
fiveruns_tuneup (0.8.20)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
jquery-rails (1.0.17, 1.0.16, 1.0.14)
json (1.6.1, 1.6.0)
libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86-linux, 3.3.10.2 x86-linux)
mail (2.3.0)
mime-types (1.17.2, 1.16)
multi_json (1.0.3)
mysql (2.8.1)
mysql2 (0.3.10, 0.3.7)
passenger (3.0.9)
polyglot (0.3.3, 0.3.2)
rack (1.3.5, 1.3.4, 1.3.2)
rack-bug (0.3.0)
rack-cache (1.1, 1.0.3)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.1.1, 3.1.1.rc1, 3.1.0)
railties (3.1.1, 3.1.1.rc1, 3.1.0)
rake (0.9.2.2, 0.9.2)
rdoc (3.11, 3.10, 3.9.4)
ruby-mysql (2.9.4)
sass (3.1.10, 3.1.7)
sass-rails (3.1.4, 3.1.1)
sprockets (2.1.0, 2.0.3, 2.0.2, 2.0.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.4)
therubyracer (0.9.9, 0.9.8)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
turn (0.8.3)
tzinfo (0.3.31, 0.3.30, 0.3.29)
uglifier (1.1.0, 1.0.4, 1.0.3)
```

Comment: @apneadiving nope. cant.